# Shader execution after writing to gl_FragDepth

Tags: opengl, glsl

Given a fragment shader that modifies the original depth of the fragment and writes to `gl_FragDepth`.
Will the code after writing to `gl_Fragdepth` still be executed if the depth test fails at that point?

Example:

```
in float depth;
layout(depth_less) out float gl_FragDepth;
void main() {
  float newDepth = depth - someModification;
  gl_FragDepth = newDepth;
  A();
}
```

Will `A` be executed if `newDepth` is greater than the current value in `gl_FragDepth`?

If so, what would be the alternative to stop the shader from doing unneccessary computations in `A` - without using a custom depth buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, A() will always be executed as long as it contributes to any output value, e.g. a color (otherwise, the compiler will remove it as an optimization). The depth test is a per-sample operation usually performed after the fragment shader. [Under special circumstances](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Early_Fragment_Test), it is possible to do this test before the fragment shader, but this requires that the fragment shader itself does not write to gl_FragDepth.

Is the modification you do a uniform one or is it different for each fragment? If it is uniform, you could do it in a geometry shader - just apply the depth modification to the whole primitive. Then you could use the early-z. If it's on per-fragment basis, you could try binding the current depth render target as a [readonly image](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Load_Store), fetch the stored depth value, perform a manual comparison in your shader and discard the fragment if it fails. However, I neither know whether you can actually bind the currently bound framebuffer's render targets as images, even as readonly, nor whether this would be more or less performant than just executing A().

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The modification depends on the fragment.

Your proposed solution worked for me when drawing geometry using glDraw*(). Since I need to draw the same geometry multiple times, I use glDraw*Instaced(), but in this case the manual depth test causes artifacts.

Anyway, that A() will always be executed as long as it contributes to any output, answers my main question.

Comment: yes... the test against gl_FragDepth could happen at any time after it's known. The card can compute overlapping fragments in any order, and the fragment depths from each computation ultimately determine which one "wins".